# Reactjs How is the weather state in <Weather /> component is undefined even though 'promise' is fullfilled?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a search filter for countries. I search a country and display their information and weather of country's capital using a weather  api. I am fetching the data of a country using axios but the `response.data` is undefined and hence its cause error.

I know the code is async. So how do I fetch data from url before I `setWeather(response.data)` .

```
const Weather = ({capital}) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
  const key = 'mykey'
  const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${key}&query=${capital}`

    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fullfilled')
      setWeather(response.data)
    })

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Weather in {weather.location.name}</h1>
      <h2>temperature: {weather.current.temperature} </h2>
      <img src = {weather.current.weather_icons} />
      <h2>wind: {weather.current.wind_speed} kph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

const PrintLanguages = ({lang}) =>{
  return(
    lang.map(l => <li key={l}>{l}</li>)
  )
}

const View = ({country}) =>{
  const lang = country.languages.map(lang => lang.name)
  return(
    <div>
          <h1>{country.name}</h1>
          <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
          <p>population {country.population}</p>
          <h2>languages</h2>
          <ul><PrintLanguages lang={lang}/></ul>
          <img src={country.flag}  alt="flag photo" height="100" width="100"/>
          <Weather capital={country.capital}/>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

[I expected this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOdil.png) but instead I am [getting this Type Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKdeh.png)
Please guide me on how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) here:

```
const Weather = ({capital}) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({location:{}, current: {}});
  const key = 'mykey'
  const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${key}&query=${capital}`

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fullfilled')
      setWeather(response.data)
    })
  }, [capital]) // Fetch the data when capital changes

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Weather in {weather.location.name}</h1>
      <h2>temperature: {weather.current.temperature} </h2>
      <img src = {weather.current.weather_icons} />
      <h2>wind: {weather.current.wind_speed} kph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will call the api method after the component is mounted.

Also make sure your initial state structure is the same as the one for the rendered state. In your case you set it to an empty array but when rendering it expects an object.

One more way is to use a `loading` state, during which you can show a loading indicator before the data fetches:

```
const Weather = ({capital}) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({location:{}, current: {}});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const key = 'mykey'
  const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${key}&query=${capital}`

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fullfilled')
      setLoading(false);
      setWeather(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : (
    <div>
      <h1>Weather in {weather.location.name}</h1>
      <h2>temperature: {weather.current.temperature} </h2>
      <img src = {weather.current.weather_icons} />
      <h2>wind: {weather.current.wind_speed} kph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Should probably use a guard on that div so when rendering the first time the code won't still get that accessing of undefined error.

Comment: That's also an option.

Comment: Yeah, you put that edit in for initial state about the same time I commented. The guard would hide the output until it is all available is about the only difference.

Comment: Yeah, also it's a better UX ;)

Comment: Add capital to the useEffect dependency so refetch occurs when capital changes.

Comment: @zhuber wasn't part of the question, but makes sense in here.

Comment: @Clarity After I display info about country how to  setWeather to a null object again ?? i.e ```setWeather({})```

Comment: @AbhishekDasgupta why would you want to do that? It would break the rendering of the component.